# When to use string and bytes type in Python3

Tags: python

In `Python 3`, the difference between string and bytes objects are explicit. But it confuses me when I need to:

- decide which one to use, and
- figure out which one is returned
  or needed as argument by a library function.

Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: I entirely cannot understand why this question is downvoted. Please leave a comment, at least. It's rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience the decision is if the data is to be stored in the computers memory or not. A string is for text that is human understandable but not directly storable in memory. If you need to store the data in memory you should be using bytes. Bytes is also useful if you need to encode your text in different formats (example: utf-8 --> utf-16)

Comment: Once it has been encoded in a format like utf-8 it is then converted to a byte string that can be effectively stored in memory.

Comment: And as far as libraries go if the function is intended to output to a file stored on a computer or take an input argument from a file stored in memory than it will be in bytes type. Alternatively if the function is intended to read or parse through a file from memory it will output in string format.